# What is each 'context' word referring to in Navigator.push?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I believe the first use of context is referring to the current context you are in, but what is the second one referring to? Is it the current one as well or is it the context of the route/screen that will appear when tapped and if it is how does flutter know which BuildContext you are referring to when they are all named the same? I really just don't get the entire second part so if someone could explain what each word is meaning/does that would be great.

```
// Within the `FirstRoute` widget
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html),

> To push a new route on the stack you can create an instance of `MaterialPageRoute` with a builder function **that creates whatever you want to appear on the screen.**

So, the second context is the context of `SecondRoute`.

Look at the prescribed example on the same page below

```dart
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute<void>(
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('My Page')),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text('POP'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
));
```

In the `onPressesd` function, you'll notice that the context that was passed into `builder` of `MaterialPageRoute` is also the context that was popped off the stack.

What other route will be popped off the stack if not the one that was pushed onto it? The context of `SecondRoute` is your answer

For the question of *how will flutter know the context of the second widget*, well, check [the doc for the `builder` property of the `Builder`class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder/builder.html) and you'll find this statement

> Called to obtain the child widget.
>
> This function is called whenever this widget is included in its parent's build and the old widget (`FirstRoute`'s in this case) that it synchronizes with has a distinct object identity (separate from `SecondRoute`'s). Typically the parent's build method will construct a new tree of widgets and so a new Builder child (`SecondRoute`'s) will not be identical to the corresponding old one.

PS: Notes in parentheses were added by me

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, context is the one, which is currently on your screen in front of you. It may be a screen, any widget, or any dialog box like AlertDialog widget. Using the code Navigator.push, you are pushing/routing/navigating the context from one screen to other.  Now the new screen becomes the present context.
    If you use Navigator.pop, the context is gone back to the place, from where it is pushed to. Let's say now an AlertDialog widget is opened. So, this widget is the current context. If you use Navigator.pop, the context becomes the previous screen/widget.
    It has some more theoretical explanation which tells about a stack, that is being used. I hope my answer gives you the idea in reality of what happens.